# Sun Grid Engine: submitted jobs by qsub command

Tags: qsub, sungridengine

I am using Sun Grid Engine queuing system.

Assume I submitted multiple jobs using a script that looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    sh qsub.sh python run.py ${i}
done
```

`qsub.sh` looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo cd `pwd` \; "$@" | qsub
```

Assuming that 5 jobs are running, I want to find out which command each job is executing.

By using `qstat -f`, I can see which node is running which jobID, but not what specific command each jobID is related to.

So for example, I want to check which `jobID=xxxx` is running `python run.py 3` and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll see it if you use `qstat -j *`. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/qstat-ge .

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try running array jobs.  Array jobs are useful when you have multiple inputs to process in the same way.  Qstat will identify each instance of the array of jobs.  See the docs for more information.

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm#-t

http://wiki.gridengine.info/wiki/index.php/Simple-Job-Array-Howto